# Getting all tuples in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Say I have the following input:

```
inp = [2, 9, 3]
```

I need output as all tuples in mixed counting, like this:

```
outp = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 2], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], ..., [1, 8, 2]]
```

I know algorithm from Knuth vol 4a as direct loop solution, but I've heard ruby has some magic inside.

I am mostly C++ developer. My direct solution now looks like:

```
inparr = [2, 9, 3]

bmix = Array.new(inparr.size) { |i| 0 }
outp = Array.new

loop do

  # some debug output
  puts bmix.to_s

  #visit next tuple
  outp << bmix.clone

  digit = inparr.size
  while digit > 0 do
    digit -= 1
    if bmix[digit] + 1 < inparr[digit]
      bmix[digit] += 1
      break
    end
    bmix[digit] = 0
  end

  break if (bmix.select{|x| x != 0}.empty?)

end
```

How to rewrite it in several simple lines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
inp.
  map { |i| (0...i).to_a }.
  reduce(&:product).
  map(&:flatten)
```

Used operations: [`Range`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Range.html), [`Enumerable#map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-map), [`Enumerable#reduce`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce), [`Array#product`](https://ruby-doc.org/Array.html#method-i-product), [`Array#flatten`](https://ruby-doc.org/Array.html#method-i-flatten).

Comment: Wow, I knew it is possible!
Can you elaborate in more details inner logic of what is happening here and why it works?

Comment: I have linked the documentation for all used operations. You might execute it step by step in REPL, examine the output and you’ll get a better understanding than after reading a book. Basically, we construct arrays zero-to-value, product them in a row and then flatten the outcome.

Comment: @KonstantinVladimirov: BTW, I am pretty sure the C++ solution looks much the same. All of those operations (and many more) are available in the C++ standard library.

Answer (score 1):

You could use recursion.

```
def recurse(inp)
  first, *rest = inp
  rest.empty? ? [*0..first-1] : (0..first-1).flat_map do |e|
     recurse(rest).map { |arr| [e, *arr] }
  end
end

recurse  [2, 4, 3]
  #=> [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 2],
  #    [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 2],
  #    [0, 2, 0], [0, 2, 1], [0, 2, 2],
  #    [0, 3, 0], [0, 3, 1], [0, 3, 2],
  #    [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 2],
  #    [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2],
  #    [1, 2, 0], [1, 2, 1], [1, 2, 2],
  #    [1, 3, 0], [1, 3, 1], [1, 3, 2]]
```

If `first, *rest = [2,4,3]`, then `first #=> 2` and `rest #=> [4,3]`.

See [Enumerable#flat_map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map) and [Array#map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map). `a ? b : c` is called a [ternery expression](https://www.thoughtco.com/ternary-or-conditional-operator-2907827).

If `e #=> 1` and `arr #=> [2,1]` then `[e, *arr] #=> [1,2,1]`.

I will go to great lengths to avoid the use of [Array#flatten](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-flatten). It's irrational, but to me it's an ugly method. That's usually possible using `flat_map` and/or the *splat* operator `*`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a mix of the 2 existing answers. It might be a bit more concise and readable:

```
head, *rest = inp.map{ |n| n.times.to_a }
head.product(*rest)
```

As an example:

```
inp = [2, 4, 3]
# => [2, 4, 3] 
head, *rest = inp.map{ |n| n.times.to_a }
# => [[0, 1], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2]] 
head.product(*rest)
# => [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 2], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 2], [0, 2, 0], [0, 2, 1], [0, 2, 2], [0, 3, 0], [0, 3, 1], [0, 3, 2], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 2], [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 0], [1, 2, 1], [1, 2, 2], [1, 3, 0], [1, 3, 1], [1, 3, 2]]
```